# Using reduce function and intersect (from dplyr) in a list of dataframes to create another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my dataframe:

```
    df<-list(structure(list(A = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A~B", "B~C", 
"C~D", "D~C", "E~F", "F~G"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A~B", 
"E~F", "H~G", "M~C", "N~D", "P~C"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "12", "2", "4", "6", "8"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("A~B", 
"H~G", "M~C", "T~C", "U~D", "W~S"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("12", "15", "18", "3", "6", "9"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```

With this command below I select the pair or pairs that are repeated on the 3 dataframes of each list position. In this case the result should be only the pair A~B:

```
the_best_pairs=Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = df)
```

Then I have this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Column `A` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector 
2: Column `V2` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector 
3: Column `A` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector 
4: Column `V2` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector
```

My original list with dataframe is much bigger and has this structure:

```
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   685 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Var1         : Factor w/ 4828 levels "ABEV3~AEDU3",..: 1016 43 37 1022 1992 1034 4004 989 986 36 ...
  ..$ Dickey_Fuller: num [1:685] -5.15 -5.06 -5.05 -5.03 -5.03 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   650 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Var1         : Factor w/ 4828 levels "ABEV3~AEDU3",..: 1016 2126 995 2746 2125 1034 1936 996 970 1992 ...
  ..$ Dickey_Fuller: num [1:650] -5.37 -5.26 -5.17 -5.08 -5.05 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   711 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Var1         : Factor w/ 4828 levels "ABEV3~AEDU3",..: 43 37 36 4065 2058 3961 975 2966 2126 66 ...
  ..$ Dickey_Fuller: num [1:711] -5.38 -5.2 -5.08 -4.83 -4.81 ...
```

I dont have any error or warning message on my original dataframe after run:`the_best_pairs=Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = dflist)` command,  but this command result an empty dataframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I using correctly this command: `the_best_pairs=Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = dflist)` ?

Any help?

Comment: the `reduce` function exist in 2 libraries. what is the package which you get it from?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara base

Comment: As you can see, from my original data the first pair ABEV3~AEDU3 is the first repeated pair. He should appear after `the_best_pairs=Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = ORIGINALDATAFRAME)` but the dataframe result is empty.

Comment: The result in your small example won't be A~B, because the values in V2 are different for each pair.... In your bigger list the value for Dickey_Fuller is also not identical accrosds the ABEV3~AEDU3 repeated pair.

Comment: @kath Its okay the values in V2 being different. I am only interesting on the repeated pairs. Probably the command should be changed right?

Comment: Yes, try `the_best_pairs = Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = lapply(df, "[[", "A"))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my mind, you get an empty result, because **your list does not have common values.**

If you run:

```
paste0(df[[1]]$A," ",df[[1]]$V2 )
 "A~B 1" "B~C 2" "C~D 3" "D~C 4" "E~F 5" "F~G 6"
paste0(df[[2]]$A," ",df[[2]]$V2 )
 "A~B 2"  "M~C 4"  "N~D 6"  "P~C 8"  "E~F 10" "H~G 12"
paste0(df[[3]]$A," ",df[[3]]$V2 )
 "A~B 3"  "M~C 6"  "U~D 9"  "T~C 12" "W~S 15" "H~G 18"
```

and it shows you, that your list does not have any intersect with each other.

You get the same result by:

```
l1<-list(paste0(df[[1]]$A," ",df[[1]]$V2 ))
l2<-list(paste0(df[[2]]$A," ",df[[2]]$V2 ))
l3<-list(paste0(df[[3]]$A," ",df[[3]]$V2 ))

li<-list(l1,l2,l3)

Reduce(dplyr::intersect,li )
```

it also gives me, an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

As already claryfied in the comments, you are are only interested in the pairs and not the condesponding values in the column `V2`.

Thus to only intersect the pairs, you can use:

```
Reduce(f = dplyr::intersect, x = lapply(df, "[[", "A"))
# [1] "A~B"
```

`lapply(df, "[[", "A")` selects the column of the pairs in each data.frame in your list returns a list and then the Reduce works as you'd expect it.